# Ant javadoc generation of tests code cannot find symbol from src code

Tags: ant, javadoc

In my project, I have a src folder with code source of the application and test folder with code source of the application tests.

In my Ant build, I would like to separate javadoc generation of these source codes. For the src code javadoc generation, there is no problem but for the tests code javadoc generation, I've got a problem because test code uses src code.

My Ant task to generate javadoc is like that :

```
<path id="classpath-test">
  <pathelement path="." />
  <pathelement path="${testclasses.home}" />
  <pathelement path="${classes.home}" />
  <fileset dir="${lib.home}" includes="*.jar" />
  <fileset dir="${libtest.home}" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<target name="compile" ... > // compiles src code of the project in ${classes.home}

<target name="compile-tests" depends="compile">
  <javac  srcdir="${test.home}"
        destdir="${testclasses.home}" 
        target="1.5"
        source="1.5" 
        debug="true"
    >
    <classpath refid="classpath-test" />
  </javac>

  <copy todir="${testclasses.home}">
    <fileset dir="${test.home}">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>

<target name="generate-javadoc-tests" depends="compile-tests" >
        <javadoc sourcepath="${test.home}" packagenames="*"
        destdir="${test-javadoc.home}" verbose="false" 
        linksource="true" encoding="${encoding}">
        <classpath refid="classpath-test" />
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

The ${test.home} variable is test folder. In the classpath-test, I put jar from junit to avoid error about annotation specifics to junit during javadoc generation. This jar is contained in ${libtest.home}.

When I generate javadoc, I have several warnings about code from test folder that using code from src folder which is normal. The errors are like that :

```
[javadoc] E:\workspace\app\test\com\app\MyClass.java:9: package com.app.SrcClass does not exist
[javadoc] symbol  : class MyClass
[javadoc] location: class com.app.MyClass
```

So, someone knows a way to includes src classes in classpath to avoid these warnings but without having source code javadoc included in test code javadoc.

Or may be a way to disable these warnings because the verbose option of javadoc task to false doesn't disable these warnings.

Comment: Could you show the source which the compiler is complaining about? Is this an `import` statement?

Comment: Yes, the sources which the compiler is complaining are : import com.app.XClass;  with the message cannot find symbol symbol : XClass.

Comment: This is not the same as what you showed in the question :-/

Comment: The name of the class XClass is just an example. I have several errors like that error with differents classes that are in source code.

Comment: The point is that this is not the error message "package ..." does not exist. This seems to indicate you have used `import com.app.SrcClass.*;` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> So, someone knows a way to includes src classes in classpath to avoid
>   these warnings but without having source code javadoc included in test
>   code javadoc.

Make sure the classes on which your tests depend are on the classpath. You might want to make your javadoc generation target dependent on the target which compiles code from src and builds a jar file. Then make sure that the classpath, referenced by refid `classpath-test` includes that jar.

Comment: I'm going to try the solution with the jar generation of source code but actually in the classpath-test there is already a pathelement pointed on the sources classes compiled. It will have the same effect that a jar I think no ?

Comment: @sylsau, sure it will have the same effect. I answered so, because at first you wrote `In the classpath-test, I put jar from junit` which is not enough.

Comment: Excuse me for the leak of precision. In fact, in classpath-test I have well the reference to source code compiled in previous task.

Comment: @sylsau anyway, it could help if you post the rest of your script

Comment: I complete the Ant script in the first post.